# Launching an external terminal in combination with Remote-SSH extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am unable to launch a true external terminal when using the [Remote-SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) in VSCode. The connecting client is running on Windows and the SSH server is proper linux (CentOS) based.

I went through all kinds of settings.json tweaks and even created various own tasks with different presentations, but none of them result in an actual new true externally launched terminal. Every time it will just add another integrated terminal in the bottom bar.

How can I force the system to launch a new terminal in a separate window that is connected to the SSH server and executes my script?

Comment: FWIW - I'm having the same challenge.